# Converting powered values to numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I have data in the following manner in `VARCHAR` format...

```
1*10^6
```

I want to present the data by resolving it into number...

```
1000000
```

How to make it possible..?

Comment: Do you store it in the format `10*10^6`?

Comment: Yes...It is in that format

Comment: Why so? Why don't you want to store it as 1000000 itself?

Comment: Requirement is like that..

Comment: Does it convert to x*(y^z) or (x*y)^z?

Comment: Converting the formula as is, 2*10^2 = 200; (2*10)^2=400.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXEC()` function but it will not work on `^` because it is an `EXCLUSIVE OR` bit operator though and `*,-,+,/ and %` are the only allowed arithmetic operators.

```
DECLARE @expr nvarchar(max)
SET @expr = '10*10'
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @expr)
```